# Turn SQL Results into Hyperlinks (Java Servlets)

Tags: java, sql, servlets, get

Essentially what i need to do, using Java Servlets and HTML only, is to GET results from the database (not a problem) and then use those results as hyperlinks.

So for example i could do `'SELECT * FROM table;'` then one of the columns would be `'ARTIST'`.

Each ARTIST result that is returned, i want to be a hyperlink.

So `'Beethoven'` should be clickable like [this](http://example.com/BEETHOVEN) .

However i need this automating so that as soon as the results are returned from the DB, they are already hyperlinks, each to their relative/respective link.

Is this is too little detail, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your view rendering technology?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt I'm using Eclipse Java EE.

Comment: How exactly are you rendering your view, e.g. with JSP, directly with the servlet etc?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt I'm using HTML buttons, which calls the Java Servlet, which the doGet() inside, connects to the database and does an SQL command such as 'SELECT * FROM table;'. This is then printed out in the Java Servlet. Out.Println.

Comment: So, how do you generate your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could build the URL address directly inside the SQL request, with concatenation ?

Say :

```
SELECT concat('http://example.com/', ARTIST) AS address FROM table
```

The syntax will depend on your database type, though.

Comment: I will give this a go now. Good idea.